# Sorting An Array Of Custom Classes In Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I need to sort an array of custom classes by a class variable. This used to be easy for me in Objective C using sort descriptors, but for some reason I cannot get that to work in Swift. I have a class like this:

```
class Show : NSObject
{
    init()
    {
        super.init()
    }

    var firstName: String!
    var lastName: String!
}
```

I am creating my array like this:

```
var peopleArray = Show[]()
```

How do I sort the array by last names?